# Expression to retrieve image from local directory in QGIS layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

I'm currently doing a project where I have to put 8 images, per page, on a layout that I previously created (as shown in the image below). My image files are always named 01, 02, 03, etc and I was thinking if there is any way that I can use an expression to retrieve a file of x name from y directory without having to put every single photo individually.

[image: Layout I'm using]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of A) custom defined project variable for the path and B) item id for the filename. Do the following steps once for the first image item you add. Then copy/paste the item as many times as you need it. Then you just have to change the Item ID accordingly for each item (step 2) to get what you want:

1. Create a project variable named `path` containing the path to the folder where the images are saved. To create the variable, go to QGIS main window > Menu Projects > Properties...  > Variables > Press green `+` icon to add the variable.
   [image]
2. Make sure each image image item in the print composer has an appropriate `Item ID`: you can fill it in in the Item Properties tab > Item ID (see screenshot below).
3. Use a data driven override for the image source with this expression: `@path || lpad (@item_id,2,'0') || '.jpg'` - see screenshot below.

If you now change the `@path` variable (step 1), you can change the path for all image items at once.

---

Explanation:

- The expression concatenates the three elements, using pipes: `||`
- `@path` returns the path to the folder you defined
- @item returns the item ID. To be sure it consists of two characters (`01` instead of `1`), use an [`lpad()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lpad) function
- `'.jpg'` adds the file extension

[image]